# How to make system properties to work on Stream Analytics to Service Bus topic

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-stream-analytics

I have a query that gets data from Event Hub. My output is Service Bus and to a topic. 
I do want to add the type of my message to the message Label for the topic. I use that for subscription rules later on.

When I put this on system properties my flow get "Degraded" and input and output complains in the azure portal when I check the Job Diagram.

System Property columns:

```
{"Label":"typeName"}
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    payload.TrackingId as trackingId,
    payload.RoI as roi,

    message.name as typeName,
```

If I change the output to cosmos Db all data stores as expected. But if I topics and add this system property the service bus output will not work. If I do not add the system property it does work. But then my rule subscription on Label does not work.

What am I missing?

Comment: `input and output complains` what's the detailed info?

Comment: The job input and output show a Orange triangle, and say:
"Additional details are not temporary available" when I hover the mouse over the input or output.

And I know the typeName exists because I get it when I set the output to cosmosDb or when I test the query..

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug, after my report, it's under development.

If you provide a system property you also need to set a Property Columns, even if it's optional.

Remember if you set a Property Column key that key will not exist in the message body, it adds to the user properties